# How to handle onmouseover and onmouseout in firefox?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, onmouseover, onmouseout, mithril.js

Hi I'm working on a mithril project

Something I notice is that my onmouseover and onmouseout is not working on firefox

Below is my code

```
let isDropdownOpen = false;

m('span.submenu', {
 class: isDropdownOpen ?  '' : 'closed',
 onmouseover: function() {
 isDropdownOpen = !isDropdownOpen;
},
 onmouseout: function() {
 isDropdownOpen = !isDropdownOpen;
 },
},
```

onclick though seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `class: isDropdownOpen ?  '' : 'closed'` in `onmouseout()` function.